# What are the rules for saying "made of [blank]"

Tags: words

Take these words for example:

> 木{もく}造{ぞう}: made of wood; wooden
>
> and
>
> 金{きん}製{せい}: made of gold

I have been under the impression that `-製` is used for where an item has been manufactured (i.e. Made in Japan; Made in America), or the manufacturing of a certain product (i.e. iron manufacturing, etc.). I also thought that `-造` was for what material something is made out of. Flipping through my dictionary it seems `-製` is more common than `-造` for referring to the material used (e.g. `鋼製: made of steel`).

Is there a rule about which materials use `-造` and which use `-製`? Is it just something one has to learn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When describing materials, the difference between -造 and -製 does not come from the difference of materials.

-造 is usually used when describing the primary material of a building or a nonbuilding structure.  Examples are 木造 (made of wood), 鉄骨造 (made of steel (or iron)), and 鉄筋コンクリート造 (made of reinforced concrete).

For everything else, I think that we use -製.  For example, “wooden flute” is 木製のフルート and not 木造のフルート.

Comment: @jkerian: I do not know.  I wrote what I think is the criterion to choose between -造 and -製: whether the thing is a building/structure or not.  Is your suggestion different from this, or is it a different way to state the same criterion?

Comment: @jkerian: It is much clearer.  Thank you for the edit!  I edited to remove the word “permanent,” because a building/structure does not have to be permanent, like 木造の仮設住宅 (wooden temporary building for residence).

Comment: An example of a nonbuilding structure? Because the primary material of a wooden flute... is wood. Is it not?

Comment: @dotnetN00b: Bridge was the only example I had in mind when I wrote this answer, but there are many examples of nonbuilding structures in Wikipedia.