# How would I say something's made of something?

Tags: translation

**Examples of what I'm asking-**

'Teeth made of gold'

'Ball made of rubber'

'House made of wood'

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5793/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

金でできている歯。ゴムでできている玉。木でできている家

Be careful of a couple of things, though. "Ball made of rubber" sounds unnaturally wordy in English, and similarly in Japanese you'd be more likely to say ゴムのボール. There's a word 木製(の) meaning "wooden." And when the materials used to make something are less obvious than a gold tooth, you're more likely to use から instead of で. For example: 糊{のり}は牛乳からできることもあります。

Comment: Yeah, the related link is more useful than my answer.